# De-indexing Collada

Tags: c, opengl, collada

How de-indexing the triangles of my collada mesh?. My goal is get something like:

```
<triangles material = "mat0" count ="12">
  <input semantic = "VERTEX" source = "#mesh1"/>
  <input semantic = "NORMAL" source = "#norm1"/>
  <p>
     0 0 1 1 4 4 3 3 5 5 7 7 6 6 8 8 .... <- same indices
  </p>
</triangles>
```

it's this possible? I use C language and OpenGL API. I want to use VBO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still use COLLADA Refinery to fix my mesh data :
http://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/COLLADA_Refinery

I have a script that goes through all my collada files doing different operations. It might have the operations you are looking for. Note that the last release was in 2007.

Full list of conditioners :
http://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/Portal:Conditioners_directory

Deindexer
http://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/Deindexer_conditioner

> Rearranges vertices indexes so that each Vertices will reference the
>   corresponding Position, Normal, Texcoord with the same index number.
>   The size of source for position, normal, and texcoord might increase.

Comment: Mmmmmhhh, Already tried it but seeing the results I get this (in a simple cube): <p> 0 1 2 2 3 0 4 5 6 6 7 4 8 9 ....etc </p> What about those that are not equal? What index should I use? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Javier: None of them are "not equal". It's giving you a *single index* per vertex. That single index is used for positions, normals, everything.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand yet. What index should I use for my drawelements? Where is the index? Could you give an example? Thank you very much.

Comment: I understood at last! those are the indices for my drawelements function. Thank you very much for your help friend. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With [meshtool](https://github.com/pycollada/meshtool) you can run the following:

```
meshtool --load_collada file.dae
         --normalize_indices
         --save_collada file-normalized.dae
```

Comment: I will have to check out meshtool then!

Comment: It's a little rough around the edges, but feel free to open an issue on github or email me if you have any issues